# Horizontal Screen scrolling + Slow framerate with usb monitor - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have been trying to setup my usb monitor as the third monitor on ubuntu 14.04
I installed the latest nvidia driver and followed the instructions on [331.113 readme randr14](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/331.113/README/randr14.html)

Basically where im at is:

I now have 3 monitors working but have errors

When I place the monitor on the right of the three:
I mouse onto the Monitor 3(usb) and it horizontally scrolls on monitor 2 so I can see monitor 3's screen on both monitor 2(scrolled) and monitor 3. I dont want that scrolling

If I place it to the left of the three I cannot mouse onto the usb monitor on the left.

Also GDM framerate is quite slow on all monitors I read on [this post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink) at the bottom about gdm framerate issues but the fix did not fix it.

Heres my current xorg.conf

```
 Section "ServerLayout"
     Identifier     "layout"
     Screen      0  "nvidia"
     Inactive "intel"
 EndSection

 Section "Device"
     Identifier     "Device0"
     Driver         "nvidia"
     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
     #BusID "01:00:0"
 EndSection

 Section "Screen"
     Identifier "nvidia"
     Device "nvidia"
     Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
 EndSection

 Section "Device"
     Identifier "intel"
     Driver "modesetting"
 EndSection

 Section "Screen"
     Identifier "intel"
     Device "intel"
 EndSection
```